# Keyboard Shortcut Changing Tabs in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, tabs

Is there a keyboard / mouse shortcut to quickly change from one tab to the next in Google Chrome?

For example, if I had two tabs open in a single window, and I wanted to easily go from the first tab to the second tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a keyboard / mouse shortcut to quickly change from one tab to the next in Google Chrome?

Windows:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> - Switch to the next/previous tab

Mac OS:

<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>/<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> - Switch to the previous tab/next tab in browsing history for tab

Source  [A wiki-style reference database for keyboard shortcuts](https://www.shortcutworld.com/)

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac to switch to the previous or next tab in your window, you can use <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd> or <kbd>}</kbd> respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> (as David suggested), you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDown</kbd>.

The advantage of this key combination is that it works in many other programs, like Nautilus and Vim.